# Spectral mapping theorem with multiplicities

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a compact linear operator on some Hilbert space; denote its spectrum by $\sigma(T)$. For every eigenvalue $\lambda\in\sigma(T)$, we can define

- the **geometric multiplicity** of $\lambda$, denoted $m_g(T,\lambda)$, as the dimension of $\ker(T-\lambda)$, and
- the **algebraic multiplicity**, denoted $m_a(T,\lambda)$, as the dimension of the range of the spectral projection
  $$P_\lambda:=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma(\lambda)}(T-z)^{-1}~dz,$$
  where $\Gamma(\lambda)$ is a Jordan curve that encloses $\lambda$ and excludes $\sigma(T)\setminus\{\lambda\}$.

If we're given a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, it is well-known from the spectral mapping theorem that
$$\sigma\big(f(T)\big)=f\big(\sigma(T)\big).$$

Is it also known what happens to the multiplicities after an application of $f$? More specifically, given an eigenvalue $\mu$ of $f(T)$, is it the case that
$$m_g\big(f(T),\mu\big)=\sum_{\lambda\in f^{-1}(\mu)\cap\sigma(T)}m_g(T,\lambda)$$
and
$$m_a\big(f(T),\mu\big)=\sum_{\lambda\in f^{-1}(\mu)\cap\sigma(T)}m_a(T,\lambda)?$$

Comment: This is certainly false for the geometric multiplicity,  a counter example being $T=\pmatrix{0&0\cr1&0}$,  $\mu=0$,
and $f(z)=z^2$. Perhaps you will have to count multiplicities when considering $f^{-1}(\mu)$.